# A relation related with odd perfect numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, perfect-numbers

It is easy to prove, using the relation $\prod_{d\mid n}d=n^{\sigma_0(n)/2}$ holds for $n\geq 1$ where $\sigma_0(n)$ is the number of divisors, the following

> **Proposition.** The integer $n\geq 1$ is a perfect number if and only if 
>   $$2^{\sigma_0(n)}\cdot\left(\prod_{d\mid n}d\right)^2=\left(\sum_{d\mid n} d\right)^{\sigma_0(n)}$$

Thus it is easy to prove, noting the sum of divisors as $\sigma(n)$, that if $n\geq 1$ is an odd perfect number then 
$$\sigma\left(\sigma(n)^{\sigma_0(n)}\right)=\left(2^{\sigma_0(n)+1}-1\right)\cdot\sigma\left(\prod_{d\mid n}d^2\right)$$

My attempt was prove the converse statement,

> **Question.** Prove that if an integer $n\geq 1$ satisfies 
>   $$\sigma\left(\sigma(n)^{\sigma_0(n)}\right)=\left(2^{\sigma_0(n)+1}-1\right)\cdot\sigma\left(\prod_{d\mid n}d^2\right)$$
>   then $n$ is odd and a perfect number (this is, an odd perfect number), or give a counterexample.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your edit Hardy

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer to your question.

Suppose $n\geq 1$ satisfies 
$$\sigma\left(\sigma(n)^{\sigma_0(n)}\right)=\left(2^{\sigma_0(n)+1}-1\right)\cdot\sigma\left(\prod_{d\mid n}d^2\right).$$
Since the RHS is odd, then
$$\sigma(n)^{\sigma_0(n)}$$
is a square or twice a square.
(I think it is possible to rule out
$$2m^2 = \sigma(n)^{\sigma_0(n)},$$
but I do not have enough time for this right now.  I will come back to this particular case later.)

If $\sigma_0(n)$ is even, then $n$ is not a square.

Suppose that
$$n = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(n)}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}.$$
Then
$$\sigma_0(n) = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(n)}{\left(\alpha_i + 1\right)}.$$
Since $\sigma_0(n)$ is even and $n$ is not a square, then at least one $\alpha_i$ is odd. (I will stop here for now, I will come back to this question (and answer) later.)

Comment: You're welcome!  =)